# Count rows that are not in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables that are for managing which profile has been used for what service.

profile table

```
CREATE TABLE public.profile
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('profile_id_seq'::regclass),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT profile_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

service table

```
CREATE TABLE public.service
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('service_id_seq'::regclass),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT service_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

used table

```
CREATE TABLE public.used
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('used_id_seq'::regclass),
    service_id bigint NOT NULL,
    profile_id bigint NOT NULL,
    insert_timestamp timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT used_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT used_profile_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (profile_id)
        REFERENCES public.profile (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT used_service_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (service_id)
        REFERENCES public.service (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I'm trying to create a SQL query that would count the total profiles that profile_id is not in the `used` table for a specific service. Let's assume our service is called 'gym', how can I count number of profiles that are not in the used table with the service name of 'gym'?

Comment: Have you tried writing a query yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to join `used` table with `service` table to access the `service text` for each `used` record. Then you need to add the condition of `service text` being equal to `gym` and finally by using `not in` condition you can select the count of profiles that don't exist in the provided subquery.

```
select count(*) from public.profile
where id not in
(select u.profile_id from public.used u inner join public.service s
 on s.id = u.service_id
where s.text = 'gym')
```